# Get node URL path using entity query

Tags: 8, entities, uri

I want to get a node path/URL via entity query. So far I've managed to fetch the title of the node.

```php
$facultyPostings = $query->get('node')
  ->condition('status', 1, '=')
  ->condition('type', 'careers')
  ->condition('field_career_directory', 'Faculty Postings', '=')
  ->sort('created')
  ->execute();

foreach ($facultyPostings as $key => $careers) {
  $careersNode = _nodeLoad($careers);
  $variables['faculty_postings'][$key]['title'] = $careersNode->get('title')->value;
  $variables['faculty_postings'][$key]['path'] = $careersNode->get('path')->value;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you want to generate. To get the \Drupal\Core\Url object for the node:

```
$node->toUrl();
```

To get a URL string:

```
$node->toUrl()->toString();
```

To get a \Drupal\Core\Link object:

```
$node->toLink();
```

To get an HTML string for the link:

```
$node->toLink()->toString();
```

`toLink()` can optionally take an argument providing a different node link. For example, the following can be used to get a link to the node edit page;

```
$node->toLink('edit-form');
```

Or to the delete page:

```
$node->toLink('delete-form');
```

The values that can be passed to `toLink()` can be determined by looking at keys of the `links` section of the annotation for the entity type. The node class lists these as:

```php
*  links = {
*    "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
*    "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
*    "delete-multiple-form" = "/admin/content/node/delete",
*    "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
*    "version-history" = "/node/{node}/revisions",
*    "revision" = "/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view",
*    "create" = "/node",
*  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the node id you can retrive it via

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
```